# Drop a member method inside type in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a type including member function. And also I have created the body type for that member function. I need a way to drop the body and member function. Dropping the body was executed. But couldn't drop the member function. So can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot drop it because the `Type` is used somewhere in any of your Object definition. See below demo:

--Create Type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EXMPL_Type AS OBJECT
(
   Team VARCHAR2 (30),
   TeamScore NUMBER (1),
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating
      RETURN NUMBER
);
/
```

--Created type body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY EXMPL_Type
AS
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
      avg_score   NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      SELECT AVG (TeamScore)
        INTO avg_score
        FROM Team_Table ;

      RETURN avg_score;
   END;
END;
/
```

-- Create a table of type

```
CREATE TABLE ABC OF EXMPL_TYPE;
```

--Dropping Type body. It got dropped

```
DROP TYPE BODY EXMPL_Type;
```

--getting Error

```
DROP TYPE EXMPL_Type;
```

Error:

```
SQL>     DROP TYPE EXMPL_Type;
    DROP TYPE EXMPL_Type
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents
```

So you need to drop `dependent` object first. In my case its the `table` which i created. Hence i drop it fisrt;

```
SQL>  DROP TABLE ABC;

Table dropped.

SQL>  DROP TYPE EXMPL_Type;

Type dropped.
```

You can find the dependent object in DBA_DEPENDENCIES table: See below:

```
SELECT REFERENCED_NAME, REFERENCED_TYPE
  FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
 WHERE name = 'EXMPL_TYPE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the type specification and body to remove the member function (or drop the body) and then recompile the specification (and body if it is still needed).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f79d/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE test_type IS OBJECT(
  value NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION getValue RETURN NUMBER
)
/

CREATE TYPE BODY test_type IS 
  MEMBER FUNCTION getValue RETURN NUMBER
  IS BEGIN RETURN self.value; END;
END;
/

DROP TYPE BODY test_type
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_type IS OBJECT(
  value NUMBER
)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT object_name, status
FROM   user_objects
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f79d/2/0)**:

```
| OBJECT_NAME | STATUS |
|-------------|--------|
|   TEST_TYPE |  VALID |
```

If the type has dependent types then you will need to drop those before you recompile the type and recreate them afterwards.